# Authorization flow for Microsoft graph API in django and react

Tags: reactjs, django, microsoft-graph-api, authorization

I am trying to integrate Microsoft Graph API with my Django backend application. I want to be able to read, manage and send emails on behalf of users.

The frontend is built with React

My issue now is how the authorization flow will work. I want users to authorize the app(prolly using Oauth) on the frontend after which I will get some kind of access code that I can save on the backend and subsequently use to make requests to the graph APIs on the user's behalf

Pls, how do I achieve this flow ??
Any help will be appreciated. I have been scrambling through the docs all day, need someone to point me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Get access on behalf of a user:

[image]

Follow this documentation for more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user